# Setting Chart.js Pie-Graph Options

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I'm having some difficulty inserting options into my displayed chart.

Here is the code, of particular note are the values under the "options" section.

```
var randomScalingFactor = function() 
{
    return Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
};
var randomColorFactor = function() {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
};
var randomColor = function(opacity) {
    return 'rgba(' + randomColorFactor() + ',' + randomColorFactor() + ',' + randomColorFactor() + ',' + (opacity || '.3') + ')';
};

var config = 
{
    type: 'pie',
    data: 
    {
        datasets: 
        [
            {
                data: 
                [
                    <?php
                        foreach($_responseArray as $_key => $_val)
                        {
                            echo("\"".$_val."\",");  
                        }
                    ?>
                ],

                backgroundColor: 
                [
                    "#F7464A",
                    "#46BFBD",
                    "#FDB45C",
                    "#949FB1",
                    "#4D5360",
                ],
            }
        ],
        labels:
        [
            <?php
                foreach($_responseArray as $_key => $_val)
                {
                    echo("\"".$_key."\",");  
                }
            ?>
        ]
    },
    options: 
    {
        scaleFontSize: 20,
        segmentStrokeColor : "#fff",
        responsive: true
    },

};

window.onload = function() 
{
    var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area").getContext("2d");
    window.myPie = new Chart(ctx, config);
};
```

Currently, none of these options are being applied *scaleFontSize*,  *segmentStrokeColor*, *responsive*, none of them work.

I have looked over the online [documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/), provided samples, and it appears this is the correct way to provide the options. However, clearly I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version you are using is v2.0. The documentation for v2.0 is at http://nnnick.github.io/Chart.js/docs-v2/

1. I don't think the pie chart has a scale, but anyway you can set it on the scale for say, a line chart (you're probably looking for `ticks.fontSize`)
2. Pie border color needs to be set on the `pie` property of `options`

   ```
      ...
      options: 
      {
          elements: {
              arc: {
                  borderColor: 'red'
              }
          }
      }
   };
   ```

   See https://jsfiddle.net/euq7fvg1/
3. `responsive` is true by default

Comment: Many thanks! Would it be possible for you to provide an example of setting the font-size for the labels?

Comment: That unfortunately doesn't work for Pie Graph, I know it needs to be on something other than yAxis, but can't quite figure out where it needs to be. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a fiddle set up with the normal sized labels? I can modify that. Cheers!

Comment: Hi, I am a little unsure how to use it, but here is the current code (Though, it doesn't work as I have pasted it in). [Link To JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/qdcgs0w5/)

Comment: um... could you attach the chart.js version you are using (and if possible replace the php tags with some dummy data). When you say labels for pie, do you mean the tooltips?